# Circus, running circusd as a daemon?

Tags: python, daemon

So, I just switched from Supervisor to Circus for controlling Python processes. I'm starting the daemon as circusd from the command line. Obviously, this isn't how I should be doing it, but I can't find any docs on the right way. Enlightenment?

Comment: Does it use SysV init scripts?  `service circus start`?

Comment: No, it doesn't.. unrecognized service

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There isn't a built in way to start circus with Upstart. I added a file `circus.conf` to `/etc/init`:

```
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE=lo
exec /usr/local/bin/circusd /etc/circus.ini
```

My circus conf is at `/etc/circus.ini`

After this I can use `sudo service circus...` to control the process.

Updated with more info here: http://nathancahill.github.com/circus/

Comment: I followed your instructions and still get `circus: unrecognized service`

Answer (score 1):

The current version of circus (0.13.0) takes a --daemon flag. So you could simply do :

```
$ circusd circus.ini --daemon
```

and send the process to background.